# item is not deleting from the database, the item should be the :item in the app.delete('/todo/:item') int the code below

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
app.delete('/todo/:item', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.params.item);
```

//here remove is not working as expected//

```
        Todo.find({item: req.params.item}).remove((err, data) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you update the data object you are trying to delete from database and the `:item` value you are passing in question?

Comment: no i am trying to use app.get, app.post and app.delete method all works but app.delete doing nothing i use ajax

Comment: $('li').on('click', function(){
      var item = $(this).text();  
      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/todo/' + item,
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the data via front-end framework
          location.reload();
        }
      });
  });

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the `remove` method with a condition:

```
Todo.remove({ item: req.params.item }, (err, data) => {
  if (err) { return res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err });

  res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

> Models have a static remove method available for removing all documents matching conditions.
>   from [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Comment: Ok have you tried:
`Todo.findOne({ item: req.params.item }).remove().exec();` ?

Comment: app.delete('/todo/:item', (req, res) => { 
        Todo.findOne({ item: req.params.item }).remove().exec((err, data) => {
            if(err) return err;
            res.json(data);
        });
        
    });